# ExtJS6: Added new record does not show up in list stores

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In extjs, when a record is created using .save that returns record with id, but does not auto show up in list store

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Please create a working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com) example that clearly shows the problem you are facing. That way we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a record using `Ext.create('MyModel')`, it is not part of any store at first. There could be more than one store which could hold it or not. Unless you add it to a specific store, it will be on its own. E.g.:

```
var model = Ext.create('MyModel',{
    field1:'ABC',
    field2:123
});
model.save({
    success:function(record) {
        if(record.get("id")%2==0) storeEven.add(record);
        else storeOdd.add(record);
    }
});
```

Unless you need that additional info from the server to decide which store to add the model to, the better way would be to add the model to the store directly, so instead of creating a model by explicit name, you can add the config to the store and then sync the store:

```
var model = store.add({
    field1:'ABC',
    field2:123
});
store.sync();
```

That way, your store knows that your model has been saved to the server. If you have used model.save to store the model on the server, and then add it to the store, and run `store.sync()` afterwards, the model will be sent to the server for a second time.